# What is the Python equivalent of PHP's set_time_limit()?

Tags: php, python

I have a python script which is freezing (I think it stalls waiting for socket data somewhere), but I am having trouble getting a backtrace because the only way to stop it is to kill the process in. There is a timeout on the socket also, but it doesn't seem to work.

I am hoping that Python has a feature like PHP's [set_time_limit()](http://www.php.net/set_time_limit) function which can stop the script and give me a useful backtrace, perhaps showing a `sock.recv()` call which is frozen, or an endless loop somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

[signal.alarm](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html?highlight=alarm#signal.alarm) can help (on Unix platforms), but (depending on the platform) there may be uninterruptable system calls (and if I get the docs right, on Unix, PHP's set_time_limit does not count time spent in system calls, so a hanging system call would be a problem there too).

Comment: Do you think signal.alarm will give him the backtrace he mentioned?

Comment: SIGALRM (or any other signal) can be handled (via signal.signal) by a handler function that gets called with the current stack frame as the second argument, so of course it's feasible (among other things) to do a stack trace from there.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a timeout on your sockets instead.

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10) #10 seconds
```

Do that at the start of your program and everything making socket connections should respect it.